# Apache 2.4 with mod_wsgi: 403 Forbidden, don't have permission to access /calbase on this server

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

So I am trying to deploy my django project on a windows server, using apache 2.4 with mod_wsgi and pythong 3.4. Before I configure httpd.conf and just try start apache with mod-wsgi installed, it works and show me that "it works" page. then I did the following configuration in httpd.conf:

```
# Change Python path used by the server.
WSGIPythonPath “/EquipmentCalibration”

# Make calls to http://localhost/ refer to the Python/WSGI-script located at the specified location.
WSGIScriptAlias / /EquipmentCalibration/equipcal/wsgi.py

# Make calls to http://localhost/static refer to the specified folder.
Alias /static/ /EquipmentCalibration/static

Alias /media/ /EquipmentCalibration/media

<Directory /EquipmentCalibration/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /EquipmentCalibration/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /EquipmentCalibration/equipcale>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

And then try to go to localhost:8080 (I changed the port from 80 to 8080), I got this error saying:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

And below is the relevant error.log.

```
[Thu Sep 29 15:05:25.171920 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7756:tid 528] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC10 Server built: Jul  9 2016 11:59:00
[Thu Sep 29 15:05:25.171920 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7756:tid 528] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'
[Thu Sep 29 15:05:25.171920 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7756:tid 528] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7524
[Thu Sep 29 15:05:25.500078 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7524:tid 456] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.4.2.
[Thu Sep 29 15:05:25.500078 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7524:tid 456] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.4.3.
[Thu Sep 29 15:05:26.171978 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7524:tid 456] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Sep 29 15:05:27.174429 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7636:tid 456] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Thu Sep 29 15:05:29.923754 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 7524:tid 1108] [client ::1:55483] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/EquipmentCalibration/equipcal/wsgi.py
```

Could somebody please help? TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The section:

```
<Directory /EquipmentCalibration/equipcale>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

has a directory name which does match what is used in the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive. One uses `equipcal` and the other `equipcale`. They need to match in that segment name.

Comment: Oh my god can't believe it was a typo..... thanks so much! Now it has some internal server error which I could work on. Thanks again